# Input string was not in a correct format in Sales Order

Tags: c#

I am having this problem

> Input string was not in a correct format.

highlighted to the part of:

> DisplayOrder(Convert.ToInt16(txtOrderNo.Text));
>   DisplayOrderDetails(Convert.ToInt16(txtOrderNo.Text));

I am having a hard time figuring out what is the error, can you help me? Thank you very much.

Here is my set codes:

```
private void displayNavigate()
{
    DisplayOrder(Convert.ToInt16(txtOrderNo.Text));
    DisplayOrderDetails(Convert.ToInt16(txtOrderNo.Text));

    double dTotal = 0;

    try
    {
        for (int nRow = 0; nRow <= grdDetails.Rows.Count - 1; nRow++)
        {
            dTotal = dTotal + Convert.ToDouble((grdDetails.Rows[nRow].Cells["Amount"].Value.ToString()));
        }
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    lblTotal.Text = string.Format("{0:#,##00.00}", dTotal);
}

//================================================================================
//================================================================================


private void DisplayOrder(int nOrderNo)
{
    try
    {
        OpenConnection();

        SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand();

        cmdSelect.Connection = cn;
        cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmdSelect.Transaction = trnOrder;
        cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT " +
            "B.OrderNo, B.OrderDate, A.CustomerNo, " +
            "A.CustomerName, A.CustomerAddress, B.PurchaseOrderNo, B.AgentName, B.Status " +
            "FROM Customers AS A, Orders AS B " +
            "WHERE A.CustomerNo = B.CustomerNo " +
            "AND B.OrderNo ='" + nOrderNo + "'";

        SqlDataReader dr = cmdSelect.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            txtOrderNo.Text = dr["OrderNo"].ToString();
            dtpOrderDate.Value = Convert.ToDateTime(dr["OrderDate"].ToString());
            txtCustomerNo.Text = dr["CustomerNo"].ToString();
            txtCustomerName.Text = dr["CustomerName"].ToString();
            txtCustomerAddress.Text = dr["CustomerAddress"].ToString();
            txtPONo.Text = dr["PurchaseOrderNo"].ToString();
            cboAgentName.Text = dr["AgentName"].ToString();
            txtOrderStatus.Text = dr["Status"].ToString();
        }
        dr.Close();
    }

    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

//================================================================================
//================================================================================

private void DisplayOrderDetails(int nOrderNo)
{
    OpenConnection();

    SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand();
    cmdSelect.Connection = cn;
    cmdSelect.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmdSelect.Transaction = trnOrder;
    cmdSelect.CommandText =
        "SELECT PackagingOutside, Quantity, Unit, ProductNo, ProductName, ProductSize, PackagingInside, " +
        "SellingDiscount, SellingPrice, Amount FROM OrderDetails WHERE OrderNo = '"
        + nOrderNo + "'";

    SqlDataAdapter daDetail = new SqlDataAdapter();
    daDetail.SelectCommand = cmdSelect;

    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    daDetail.Fill(ds, "OrderDetails");

    grdDetails.DataSource = null;
    grdDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables["OrderDetails"];
}
```

Comment: `txtOrderNo.Text` most likely contains non-numeric characters.  I'd suggest `Int32.TryParse` for a safer conversion.

Comment: "Input string was not in a correct format" means the input string is not a valid number.What is the value of txtOrderNo.Text?

Comment: Also, get in the habit of using Parameterized Queries - otherwise you'll leave the SQL Injection door wide open.

Comment: what is the value of txtOrderNo.Text when it tries to convert? Make sure it's not empty - Should refresh page before asking questions :p

Comment: first validate text box so check it not empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `Convert.ToInt16` you will get this exception if *value does not consist of an optional sign followed by a sequence of digits (0 through 9)*

Do a validation for inputs before proceed like below.

```
int orderNo;
if (int.TryParse(txtOrderNo.Text, out orderNo))
{
    DisplayOrder(orderNo);
    DisplayOrderDetails(orderNo);
}
```

Side Note :

don't share the `SqlConnection` create new instant when you need it and wrap it with using block like below

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{

}
```

Use SQL Parameters

```
cmdSelect.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Orders WHERE OrderNo = @OrderNo";
cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OrderNo", nOrderNo);
```

Comment: If the conversion to `Int16` is successful, wouldn't the framework automatically do an implicit conversion to `Int32`, since it's a widening conversion?

Comment: but you know the Range of `Int16 ` and `Int32` different, not this exception but will get another exception if out of range value given for `Int16 `

Comment: Agreed, and you answer is technically correct but could be a little misleading - if the value entered in `txtOrderNo.Text` is *successfully* converted to an `Int16`, the system will conduct an implicit cast from `Int16` to `Int32`, since the maximum value for an `Int32` will accommodate the max value for an `Int16`.

Comment: @Tim I have removed that statement. `int.TryParse` will give `int` value and no need of a cast at the end

Comment: Definitely the better way to go. +1

Answer (score 0):

This means that the value in txtOrderNo.Text is not considered an integer. You will get this error if your textbox is empty.

Either check that the textbox contains data, or use the TryParse (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx) method

Answer (score 0):

There are two things to consider,

1. Values entered in the textbox should be an integer in the range of 16 bit, if it can be bigger value, then you have to think of going to long, int32 etc.
2. Validate the textbox using `TryParse()` which will tell you whether it has valid value entered.